# json-readtable-error during org-capture

Tags: debugging, org-capture, json

This problem only arose today and I haven't really changed anything substantial in my init.el so I am sure what the source of the error is. Essentially, when running `org-capture` (and also during startup) I get `(json-readtable-error)`. When I set `debug-on-error` to be true, but could not find anything useful (debugger output is below).

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Capture abort: (json-readtable-error)")
  signal(error ("Capture abort: (json-readtable-error)"))
  error("Capture abort: %s" (json-readtable-error))
  #[512 "\203�  \306=\203�\307\310\232!\311\232\203�\312 \207\313\232\203\"�\314 \207p\315\303!\2034�\2034�\316\f\317\"\202A�\3201?�\321\322!0\202A�\210\322
\206H�\323!\322@\206W�\324 \205W�`\325 {\262\211;\203f�\326\327G\330$\210;\203t�\326\327G\331$\210\332\232\203\200�\333\334!\202\222\335\232\203\214�\336\337!\202\222\340!\210\341 \210\342\343\344\345!\206\253�\346\347!\205\253�\350A\"@\351\345\n!\205\271�\352\345!!\317\n\353\n\354\355 \356\n\206\311�\357 &\210\360 \210\3611\334�\342\362\363 \"0\202\354�\364\365!\203\346�\366\365!\210\367\370\"\262\210\371\372!B\327\232\203\375�\373 \202\222\3741
\375\371\376!@\377=!0\202>\201E�p!\203'\201F�\201G�\201H� \"\203'\366p!\210\201I�\371\354!!\210\367\201J�\371\201K�!A@#\262\210\201L�\201M�!\203\206\371\201N�!\203\206\201O�1\201\201P� \203j\342\201Q�\201R�C!\"\210\201S� \210\201T�\201D�!\210\201U�\211D0\202\205\210\202\206\210\371\201V�!\205\222\201W� \207" [org-capture-use-agenda-date major-mode org-overriding-default-time org-capture-link-is-already-stored org-store-link-plist org-capture-entry org-agenda-mode org-get-cursor-date 1 (4) org-capture-goto-target (16) org-capture-goto-last-stored boundp plist-get :annotation (error) org-store-link nil org-capture-select-template org-region-active-p mark remove-text-properties 0 (read-only t) (read-only t) "C" customize-variable org-capture-templates "q" user-error "Abort" org-capture-set-plist org-capture-get-template org-capture-put :original-buffer :original-file buffer-file-name featurep dired rassq :original-file-nondirectory file-name-nondirectory :initial :return-to-wconf current-window-configuration :default-time org-current-time org-capture-set-target-location (error quit) ...] 21 ("/Users/bibekpokharel/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20180129/org-capture.elc" . 23542) "P"](nil nil)
  ad-Advice-org-capture(#[512 "\203�    \306=\203�\307\310\232!\311\232\203�\312 \207\313\232\203\"�\314 \207p\315\303!\2034�\2034�\316\f\317\"\202A�\3201?�\321\322!0\202A�\210\322
\206H�\323!\322@\206W�\324 \205W�`\325 {\262\211;\203f�\326\327G\330$\210;\203t�\326\327G\331$\210\332\232\203\200�\333\334!\202\222\335\232\203\214�\336\337!\202\222\340!\210\341 \210\342\343\344\345!\206\253�\346\347!\205\253�\350A\"@\351\345\n!\205\271�\352\345!!\317\n\353\n\354\355 \356\n\206\311�\357 &\210\360 \210\3611\334�\342\362\363 \"0\202\354�\364\365!\203\346�\366\365!\210\367\370\"\262\210\371\372!B\327\232\203\375�\373 \202\222\3741
\375\371\376!@\377=!0\202>\201E�p!\203'\201F�\201G�\201H� \"\203'\366p!\210\201I�\371\354!!\210\367\201J�\371\201K�!A@#\262\210\201L�\201M�!\203\206\371\201N�!\203\206\201O�1\201\201P� \203j\342\201Q�\201R�C!\"\210\201S� \210\201T�\201D�!\210\201U�\211D0\202\205\210\202\206\210\371\201V�!\205\222\201W� \207" [org-capture-use-agenda-date major-mode org-overriding-default-time org-capture-link-is-already-stored org-store-link-plist org-capture-entry org-agenda-mode org-get-cursor-date 1 (4) org-capture-goto-target (16) org-capture-goto-last-stored boundp plist-get :annotation (error) org-store-link nil org-capture-select-template org-region-active-p mark remove-text-properties 0 (read-only t) (read-only t) "C" customize-variable org-capture-templates "q" user-error "Abort" org-capture-set-plist org-capture-get-template org-capture-put :original-buffer :original-file buffer-file-name featurep dired rassq :original-file-nondirectory file-name-nondirectory :initial :return-to-wconf current-window-configuration :default-time org-current-time org-capture-set-target-location (error quit) ...] 21 ("/Users/bibekpokharel/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20180129/org-capture.elc" . 23542) "P"] nil)
   apply(ad-Advice-org-capture #[512 "\203� \306=\203�\307\310\232!\311\232\203�\312 \207\313\232\203\"�\314 \207p\315\303!\2034�\2034�\316\f\317\"\202A�\3201?�\321\322!0\202A�\210\322
\206H�\323!\322@\206W�\324 \205W�`\325 {\262\211;\203f�\326\327G\330$\210;\203t�\326\327G\331$\210\332\232\203\200�\333\334!\202\222\335\232\203\214�\336\337!\202\222\340!\210\341 \210\342\343\344\345!\206\253�\346\347!\205\253�\350A\"@\351\345\n!\205\271�\352\345!!\317\n\353\n\354\355 \356\n\206\311�\357 &\210\360 \210\3611\334�\342\362\363 \"0\202\354�\364\365!\203\346�\366\365!\210\367\370\"\262\210\371\372!B\327\232\203\375�\373 \202\222\3741
\375\371\376!@\377=!0\202>\201E�p!\203'\201F�\201G�\201H� \"\203'\366p!\210\201I�\371\354!!\210\367\201J�\371\201K�!A@#\262\210\201L�\201M�!\203\206\371\201N�!\203\206\201O�1\201\201P� \203j\342\201Q�\201R�C!\"\210\201S� \210\201T�\201D�!\210\201U�\211D0\202\205\210\202\206\210\371\201V�!\205\222\201W� \207" [org-capture-use-agenda-date major-mode org-overriding-default-time org-capture-link-is-already-stored org-store-link-plist org-capture-entry org-agenda-mode org-get-cursor-date 1 (4) org-capture-goto-target (16) org-capture-goto-last-stored boundp plist-get :annotation (error) org-store-link nil org-capture-select-template org-region-active-p mark remove-text-properties 0 (read-only t) (read-only t) "C" customize-variable org-capture-templates "q" user-error "Abort" org-capture-set-plist org-capture-get-template org-capture-put :original-buffer :original-file buffer-file-name featurep dired rassq :original-file-nondirectory file-name-nondirectory :initial :return-to-wconf current-window-configuration :default-time org-current-time org-capture-set-target-location (error quit) ...] 21 ("/Users/bibekpokharel/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20180129/org-capture.elc" . 23542) "P"] nil)
  org-capture(nil)
   funcall-interactively(org-capture nil)
  call-interactively(org-capture nil nil)
  command-execute(org-capture)
```

Comment: Maybe try (1) load the source file that defines command `org-capture` and then (2) `M-x debug-on-entry org-capture`. Then step through the debugger using `d` to see what goes wrong. But before doing that, check that you see the same problem when starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file). If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Drew. For anyone who is curious, adding the following code in the init.el solved the issue. Turns out emacs was not being able to load json setup. (when (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize)).

Answer (score 2):

I received the exact same error on a fresh Ubuntu install using Emacs 26.3. In my case it was related to the `ob-ipython` packet, which requires `ipython` and `jupyter` to be installed, which I hadn't come around to doing yet. After a `sudo apt install ipython jupyter` the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is curious, adding the following code in the `init.el` solved the issue. Turns out Rmacs was not being able to load JSON setup because it was looking in the wrong folder. I also had to install the package `exec-path-from-shell`.

```
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns x)) (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```